# How can I find the longest words in the string and return those (excluding duplicates) along with maximum length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I know how I can find the longest word in a string. For example this code here.
But here the problem is that the word "bbbbbb" is found because he is the
FIRST LONGEST WORD IN THE string,after that with 6 chars we have also the word "jumped". My question is how can I find in this case and the word "jumped",so all of them not only the first one.

UPDATE: I want unique list, so only one of each words

```js
function longestWord(sentence) {
  sentence = sentence.split(' ');

  let theWord = sentence[0];
  var longest = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if (sentence[i] != "") {
      if (sentence[i].length > theWord.length) {
        longest = sentence[i].length;
        theWord = sentence[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    length: longest,
    actuallWord: theWord
  }
}
console.log(longestWord("The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the bbbbbb lazy dog"));
```

Comment: Try `sentence.filter(w => w.length === longest)` to get an array of words with that length.

Comment: You can try creating an array to hold the longest words that you add to. Then you can use filter() or map() to evaluate length and add to the array.

Comment: You have two answers with unique words now: [Yevhen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60153072/295783) and [FZs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60153437/295783)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
function longestWord(sentence) {
  // First we divide the sentence into words
  var words = sentence.split(' ');
  
  // We then get the length by getting the maximun value of the length of each word
  var length = Math.max(...words.map(a=>a.length));
  return {
    length: length,
    // Finally we filter our words array returning only those of with the same length we previously calculated
    words: words.filter(i => i.length == length)
  }
}
console.log(longestWord("The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: Nice one to get the length in one statement. I need more because .sort does not return the array

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Why not add an explanation anyway? It's good for other readers that find this answer. In addition to the OP.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Your solutuon is also great.thanks mate

Comment: Above solution **does not skip duplicating words** and the algorithm being implemented is not optimal as it **unnecessarily requires 2 passes through the array** whereas [single pass approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60153072/11299053) may gain about 15% [better performance](https://jsbench.me/vdk6gm0pk7/1) even for such a short test string.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov You're right about performance, but I'm not sure whether the OP wanted to get unique words (that part was [edited in the question by others](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60152850/revisions))

Comment: Single-pass is definitely the way to go, but it's worth keeping in mind that declarative code which hardly makes use of function calls will always [test faster](https://jsbench.me/idk6ijgici/1) - function calls have overhead!

Comment: @Gershom : 3 of code snippets you're benchmarking return 3 different results. Valid version of your benchmark would rather look like [this](https://jsbench.me/zgk6j0r8g2/1). However, my point here is rather simple: 2 passes are absolutely unnecessary to solve such problem. The way you do single pass - is up to you, as being said, to me `for...` loops aesthetically don't worth performance gain they *may* deliver, I prefer high-order methods for the way they look, the way they chain, etc.

Comment: I'm not at all arguing that the fastest solution is always the best solution! We should be concerned with readability and maintainability as well. But it's good for people to be aware of the performance, since many people like to copy/paste from stack overflow without too much thought.

Answer (score 2):

You may do that with `Array.prototype.reduce()` by a single pass through the array (without extra looping for calculating maximum length).

The idea is to reset resulting array with a single word, once its length exceeds those that were inserted before or append if current word happens to have same length, or simply pass by otherwise:

```js
const src = 'The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the jumped lazy dog',

      result = src.split(' ')
                  .reduce((res, word, idx) => {
                    if(!idx || word.length > res.length)
                        res = {length: word.length, words:new Set([word])}
                    else if(word.length == res.length)
                        res.words.add(word)
                    return res
                  }, {})

console.log({result: result.length, words: [...result.words]})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

Comment: It is a virtue to allow a noob to understand what is going on too :)

Comment: I would say this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60153437/295783 is more readable. Any comments?

Comment: Nested ternaries are hideous and dangerous. Your quest for single line solutions will make the coder after you hate you big time :)

Comment: I find reduce isn't too great for updating multiple values together (in this case, `length` and `words`).

Answer (score 2):

You could take a single loop approach and check the legth fot each word with the accumulators length of the first item.

```js
function longestWords(words) {
    return words
        .split(/\s+/)
        .reduce((accu, word) => {
            if (!accu[0] || accu[0].length < word.length) return [word];
            if (accu[0].length === word.length) accu.push(word);
            return accu;
        }, []);
}

console.log(longestWords("The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: @mplungjan: Interesting how different styles appeal to different people.  I find this one of the easier answers to read.  Of course maybe that's because it's similar to the answer I wrote... but didn't publish because Nina beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by reducing the `sentence` array.

The advantage of this approach is that it loops over the array only once:

```js
function longestWords(sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').reduce((output, word) => {
    if (word.length > output.length) {
      output.words = [word]
      output.length = word.length
    } else if (word.length === output.length) {
      output.words.push(word)
    }
    return output
  }, { length: 0, words: [] })
}
console.log(longestWords("The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Or, if you want to filter out duplicate words, you could return a `Set` instead:

```js
function longestWords(sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').reduce((output, word) => {
    if (word.length > output.length) {
      output.words.clear()
      output.length = word.length
    } 
    if (word.length >= output.length) {
      output.words.add(word)
    }
    return output
  }, { length: 0, words: new Set })
}
const words = longestWords("The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the jumped lazy dog")
console.log(words.length);
console.log(Array.from(words.words)) //Just to make StackSnippets console show the Set's entries
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check if the word's length is greater or equal to the length of the first item of the array (All the items in the array should have the same length).

If so, then check if it is greater. If that is true, then set the array to that word, because you found a word that was bigger than the words in the array. Otherwise, add it to the array of the words that have the greatest length.

```js
function longestWord(sentence) {
  sentence = sentence.split(' ');
  let theWord = sentence[0];
  var longest = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if (sentence[i] != "") {
      if (sentence[i].length >= theWord[0].length) {
        if (sentence[i].length > theWord[0].length) {
          longest = sentence[i].length;
          theWord = [sentence[i]];
        } else {
          theWord.push(sentence[i])
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    length: longest,
    actuallWord: theWord
  }
}
console.log(longestWord("The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done in single reduce.
Initiated with the object.

```js
function longestWord(words) {
  return words
    .split(/\s+/)
    .reduce((acc, word) => {
   if(word.length > acc.length) {
    acc.length = word.length;
    acc.words = [word];
   }
   else if (word.length === acc.length) {
    acc.words.push(word);
   }
   return acc;
  }, {length:0, words:[]});
}

console.log(longestWord("The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach doesn't have a better time complexity than the best answers here, but it does have better coefficients. (It only loops over the array of words once, no function calls except for `Array.prototype.push`).

```js
let allLongestItems = items => {
  let longest = [];
  let length = 0;
  for (let item of items) {
    let len = item.length;
    if (len === length) longest.push(item)
    else if (len > length) { longest = [ item ]; length = len; }
  }
  return { items: longest, length };
};

let str = 'The quick brown as bbbbbb fox jumped over the lazy dog';
console.log(allLongestItems(str.split(' ')));
```